# PCA from FactoMineR::PCA() not returning same as base::prcomp()

Tags: r, pca

Doing some PCA analysis and when comparing with the results for `FactoMineR` function `PCA` together with `prcomp` from `base` I dont get the same results. One example

```
library(ISLR)
library(FactoMineR)
data("NCI60")

df <- NCI60$data


pca_prcomp <- prcomp(df, scale. = T)
pca_facto <- FactoMineR::PCA(df, scale.unit = T, graph = F, ncp = 65)


# One column is missing

dim(pca_prcomp$x)
dim(pca_facto$ind$coord) 

# Values are similiare - but not the same

head(pca_prcomp$x[, 1:2])
head(pca_facto$ind$coord[, 1:2])


# Using scale function - does not return same values

pca_facto_scale <- PCA(scale(df), scale.unit = F, graph = F, ncp = 65)

head(pca_facto$ind$coord[, 1:2], 3)
head(pca_facto_scale$ind$coord[, 1:2], 3)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for being late, the `FactoMineR` package uses the same approach of `svd()` which should be similar (but not identical) with the `prcomp()` approach and both of them are listed under the Q-mode, which is the preferred method to do PCA for its numerical accuracy. But note, I didn't say identical, why? `FactoMineR` uses its own algorithm for PCA where it calculates the number of components like the following:

```
ncp <- min(ncp, nrow(X) - 1, ncol(X))
```

which tells you clearly why you got number of components 63 not 64 as what `prcomp()` would normally give. Your data set is typical of genomics data where you have `n` rows smaller than `p` columns of genes and the above code will clearly take columns or rows, whichever has the less number. If you follow the `svd()` algorithm it will return 64 dimensions not 63.

To explore the source code further type `FactoMineR:::PCA`.

For differences between the Q-mode (`svd`, `prcomp()`, `FactoMineR::PCA()`)  and R-mode (`eigen()`, `princomp()`) I would recommend visiting this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9522/22518).

**Side note**: for `prcomp()` you want pass the `center = T` argument in order to center your data before doing PCA. Scaling on the other hand will give all your gene columns equal weight.

```
pca_prcomp <- prcomp(df, center = T, scale. = T) # add center=T
```

For scaling, the `prcomp()` use `N` as the divisor while `FactoMineR::PCA()` uses `N-1` instead. The code below will prove it (refer to the same linked answer above):

```
# this is the scaled data by scale()
df_scaled <- scale(df)

# then you need to get the standardized data matrix from the output of the FactoMineR::PCR() function, which can be done easily as follows:
df_restored <- pca_facto$svd$U %*% diag(pca_facto$svd$vs) %*% t(pca_facto$svd$V)

# the to make both FactoMineR::PCR() and scale() match up you need to do the correction
df_corrected <- df_restored * sqrt(63 / 64) # correct for sqrt(N-1/N)

head(df[, 1:5]) # glimpse the first five columns only!
head(df_scaled[, 1:5])
head(df_restored[, 1:5]) # glimpse the first five columns only!
head(df_corrected[, 1:5])
round(head(df_scaled[, 1:5]), 3) == round(head(df_corrected[, 1:5]), 3) # TRUE

R> head(df[, 1:5])
       1      2      3      4      5
V1 0.300  1.180  0.550  1.140 -0.265
V2 0.680  1.290  0.170  0.380  0.465
V3 0.940 -0.040 -0.170 -0.040 -0.605
V4 0.280 -0.310  0.680 -0.810  0.625
V5 0.485 -0.465  0.395  0.905  0.200
V6 0.310 -0.030 -0.100 -0.460 -0.205
R> head(df_scaled[, 1:5])
       1        2      3      4      5
V1 0.723  1.59461  1.315  1.345 -0.600
V2 1.584  1.73979  0.438  0.649  0.905
V3 2.173 -0.01609 -0.346  0.264 -1.301
V4 0.678 -0.37256  1.615 -0.441  1.235
V5 1.142 -0.57720  0.958  1.130  0.359
V6 0.746 -0.00289 -0.185 -0.120 -0.476
R> head(df_restored[, 1:5])
      [,1]     [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
[1,] 0.729  1.60722  1.326  1.356 -0.605
[2,] 1.596  1.75354  0.442  0.654  0.912
[3,] 2.190 -0.01622 -0.349  0.266 -1.311
[4,] 0.683 -0.37550  1.628 -0.444  1.244
[5,] 1.151 -0.58176  0.965  1.139  0.361
[6,] 0.752 -0.00291 -0.186 -0.121 -0.480
R> head(df_corrected[, 1:5])
      [,1]     [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
[1,] 0.723  1.59461  1.315  1.345 -0.600
[2,] 1.584  1.73979  0.438  0.649  0.905
[3,] 2.173 -0.01609 -0.346  0.264 -1.301
[4,] 0.678 -0.37256  1.615 -0.441  1.235
[5,] 1.142 -0.57720  0.958  1.130  0.359
[6,] 0.746 -0.00289 -0.185 -0.120 -0.476
R> round(head(df_scaled[, 1:5]), 3) == round(head(df_corrected[, 1:5]), 3)
      1    2    3    4    5
V1 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
V2 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
V3 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
V4 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
V5 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
V6 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

**Book excerpt**

There is also the book for `FactoMineR` package called "Exploratory Multivariate Analysis by Example Using R" 2nd edition by François Husson, Sébastien, and Lê Jérôme Pagès. Below is an excerpt from page 55 of the book which was discussing a data set from a genomic study similar to yours with `n` rows (43) far less than `p` 7407 columns `chicken.csv` data set, you can see more info in their website as well as the data set itself can be downloaded from this [link](http://factominer.free.fr/bookV2/).

[image]

Comment: I have genomic data as well, but in may case I have more rows (individuals) than columns (genes). Should this be some interferent to use FactoMineR?

Comment: Hi, you can use whatever package you want, but FactoMineR in my opinion is user-friendly and would streamline many processes for you. It is also user-friendly, try Factoshingy to know what I mean, you can do a lot with it interactively. It is actively maintained by its authors and recently they rolled out Factoinvestigate for results interpretation. It is also well documented, there is a book and many tutorial videos. Check out the website: http://factominer.free.fr/index.html

Comment: To your point, having more rows (individuals) than columns (genes), has nothing to do with what package you should work with. But anyway, you *can* use FactoMineR.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is most likely between the eigenvalue and SVD methods for performing PCA (see [this great answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca) for some details.

From `?prcomp`:

> The calculation is done by a singular value decomposition of the
>        (centered and possibly scaled) data matrix, not by using ‘eigen’
>        on the covariance matrix.  This is generally the preferred method
>        for numerical accuracy.

From ?PCA:

> Returns a list including:
>        eig: a matrix containing all the eigenvalues, the percentage of
>             variance and the cumulative percentage of variance